# how to run bash nested function

Tags: bash, function, nested

I have a function:

```
volume () { 
up
down​
}
up () { echo 'up' }
down () { echo 'down' }
declare -f a
```

I'm able to run function volume, up, or down without the problem but my question is:

How to run function up or or down as the sub function of volume?  for example:

```
volume up
or
volume down
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired effect, I'd write it that way:

```
volume () { 
    if [ "$1" == "up" ] || [ "$1" == "down" ] ; then
        eval $1
    fi
}
up () { echo 'up'; }
down () { echo 'down'; }
```

Comment: This works perfect thank you!
The only problem I see here is that bash_completion will not work with that approach

Comment: You're welcome. To turn on and off bash completion, you could have a look at: https://embraceubuntu.com/2006/01/28/turn-on-bash-smart-completion/#
But beware: the bash completion mostly auto-completes file name from file it finds in the current directory and/or the path. In your case, this is not about filenames,  but about function names, so, you'd have to implement the auto completion all by yourself... I don't know the nuts and bolts of it, just that it is possible.